# App roles & groups claim (emitted as roles) in Azure Active Directory App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac, azure-service-principal, azure-app-registration

I have registered an **Azure AD Application** with an `App role` called `read`.

### User Principal

If a user principal is assigned to the app role `read` and the `groups` claim (`emit_as_roles` enabled) is added in the Azure AD App, only the AAD security groups show up in the user's token (`roles` claim) but not the app roles the user has been assigned to.

This is mentioned in the documentation:

> [If "emit_as_roles" is used, any application roles configured that the user is assigned won't appear in the role claim.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims)

### Service Principal

Apparently, the same seems to apply for **Service Principals**, even though

> [Service principals won't have group optional claims emitted in the JWT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims).

As expected, disabling (default) the `emit_as_roles` setting in the token configuration allows me to see the information `read` in the `roles` claim again.

---

I assume that this is the *expected* behaviour for **service principals** in Azure AD. However, the documentation only mentions this for users but not for service principals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. This is the  expected behavior for both users and service principals in Azure AD.

As service principals are security principal  for a service ,but in user terms it is user principal .

So when the "emit_as_roles" is enabled for the groups claim, any application roles assigned to the user or service principal will not appear in the roles claim.

I have checked the token:
When enabled emit_as_roles in the groups claim:

[image]

Authorize url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxbb5&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&grant_type =authorization_code&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
```

Token url

token claims:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token`

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/4xx/",
  "iat": 1684912827,
  "nbf": 1684912827,
  "exp": 1684917432,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "AYQAexxxx",
  "altsecid": "5::100xx14397",
  "amr": [
    "rsa",
    "mfa"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "kavyarepo",
  "appid": "xxx",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "email": "xxx@microsoft.com",
  "family_name": "Kavya",
  "given_name": "xx",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxx/",
  "idtyp": "user",
  "ipaddr": "115.110.154.186",
  "name": "xxx",
  "oid": "xxx",
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": "100xxxC5",
  "rh": "0.xxxx.",
  "scp": "Directory.AccessAsUser.All openid profile User.Read User.Read.All email",
  "sub": "xxxx",
  "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
  "tid": "xxx",
  "unique_name": "xxx@microsoft.com",
  "uti": "p6nDIxxxxsjAzAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    "xxxx",
    "xxxx",
    "xxx"
  ],
```

[image]

If  application roles need to be included in token, for both user and service principals, the "emit_as_roles" option must be disabled.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this!
What's the right channel to suggest changes in the docs? The MS docs GitHub repo?

Instead of `user`, `security principal` would be more correct as this includes both, user & service principals.